# Sometimes RDS CPU utilization is going to very high

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are using AWS RDS in MySQL For our app purpose. Normally that Cpu Utilization is running on 40% to 60%. Sometimes that CPU Utilization is going to be very high. That maintains 100% of CPU Utilization. I don't know-how is that possible and How I solve this. But, When I Upgrade our DB engine the problem was solved. After 3 days I downgrade the DB engine the CPU working fine. Two months later again the same problem is created. Again I upgrade and downgrade the CPU Engine.

Does anyone explain How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What configuration are you running? Is the load on the database explainable given the load on your application etc?

Comment: Additional information request. 
AWS RDS Model being used, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
F) complete www.MySQLTuner.pl (perl) report or similar. 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: What are the Model's you are changing to, each time with your AWS RDS hosting?  Staying in the same Availability Zones?

Comment: every time I am changed db.t3.xlarge to db.t3.2xlarge. also with the same region and availability zone.

Comment: If you could provide the additional information requested above on Aug 16, 2021 at 23:30 we will likely find my.cnf or my.ini changes to make this repetitive change unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If the CPU Utilization is 40% - 60% normally, most likely there is a query running long to make the CPU Utilization to 100%.

Have you tried to run `show full processlist` during 100% CPU Utilization to find out if there is a long runtime query?

I would suggest the reason of upgrading and downgrading action solves the problem is that it is rebooted the RDS and killed the long runtime query.